# Django How to gather HTML for {% include %} and assign to JS variable

Tags: javascript, django, jspdf

I am using JSPDF to convert HTML to a PDF. This is extremely simple if I have a rendered page and then clicking a button just exports the appropriate PDF, however, I am attempting to create a receipt via JSPDF and rendering the page prior to providing the PDF is not a good option.

With this, I am using Django and basically what I want to do is use a template's html to render the receipt I need:

For example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.min.js"></script>

let doc = new jsPDF();
$('#click').click(function () {
   let a  = {% include 'receipt_template.html' with data=payment_data %};
   doc.fromHTML(a, 0, 0, {
      'width': 170
   });
   doc.save('receipt.pdf');
});
```

But this is not working as I am not gathering the template's HTML, I am literally rendering it on the page. Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign html code to your `a` variable.

Just quote your included template - update this code to:

```js
let a  = `{% include 'receipt_template.html' with data=payment_data %}`;
```

**Update**

As [@Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323619/django-how-to-gather-html-for-include-and-assign-to-js-variable/58323782?noredirect=1#comment103006224_58323782) said, there can be escaping problem.

In my example you can't use `` ` `` in `receipt_template.html` and included to it. You need to escape them.

**Update 2**

Also you can use JSX to process included template directly to js variable.

Then your code will be similar to this:

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  let doc = new jsPDF();
  $('#click').click(function () {
   let a  = ({% include 'receipt_template.html' with data=payment_data %});
   doc.fromHTML(a, 0, 0, {
    'width': 170
   });
   doc.save('receipt.pdf');
  });
</script>
```

However you should almost never need to use this approach.

Comment: But this will break if there are any quotes at all inside the rendered template, which there almost certainly would be.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated answer to use backticks instead of quotes but escaping is another question here - I don't know what can be in ```receipt_template.html```.

Comment: @Yevhenii, I ended up using async tasks via backend logic and celery to render the PDF using WeasyPrint, but I'll mark this correct because it would have solved my task specifically to the instance I was describing, the WeasyPrint option was more robust, but not important to the context of this question. I always seem to forget about backtics, nice idea! They aren't used often in HTML, unless I have JS